# What are the Pros/Cons of Flash Builder vs. FlashDevelop?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ide, flashdevelop

I want to play around a bit with FLASH for app development. I'm looking for a good IDE for that.  Someone suggested Flash Develop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Major reason to use FlexBuilder: has a real debugger you can set breakpoints and single step and watch/edit variables.

Unless FlashDevelop has .. developed .. don't think it got any of that yet.

BTW - if you are a student/teacher FlexBuilder can be had for *free*

Comment: Agreed. Debugger is the make/break feature for an IDE.

Comment: The Debugger and the Design view makes Flex/Flash Builder awesome. I would definitely suggest it

Comment: Flash Develop have fully featured debugger

Comment: Bullshit. FlashDevelop has been shipping with a "real debugger" with breakpoints and single stepping for the last 3 years.

Comment: Realize the original answer here is almost 5 years old, but it couldn't be farther from the truth. As others have mentioned, FD has taken huge steps, and comes with a full featured debugger.

Answer (score 24):

**Flash Builder**

*Pros*

- better debugging and profiling
- visual designer for MXML
- because of Eclipse: support for other languages (eg. with Aptana, PDT...) and usage of plug-ins for the Eclipse Platform with features not shipped with FlexBuilder (code snippets with CFEclipse "Dynamic Snippets", "auto-code" for getter/setters with Monkey scripts...)
- support of virtual folders/files (links to external files/folders handled intern by Eclipse, so also working on Windows)
- refactoring (renaming of classes, functions, properties with automatic changing of dependencies)

*Cons*

- Commercial license
- Big and because of Eclipse problematic with newer Eclipse versions for the FlexBuilder plug-in version (eg. not working with Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.1)
- adding and configuring the missing features with Eclipse plug-ins needs time and searching in the Internet (which plug-in? settings etc.)
- Code assist only average and sometimes buggy eg. if correct imports are missing ("java.lang.NullPointerException")
- missing of a code formatter or automatic get/setters (but there are solutions with other Eclipse plugins like Monkey Scripts, CFeclipse, Flexformatter "FlexPrettyPrintCommand"...)
- sometimes a bit sluggish if background tasks in Eclipse are working
- no package explorer
- AS2 and AS3 only - no Haxe

**FlashDevelop**

*Pros*

- free and Open Source (developed with C#)
- lightweight and snappy
- best available Code Assist for ActionScript
- supports all flash languages - AS2, AS3, haxe
- "auto code" for automatic getter/setter, variables, code for event handlers
- code snippets with integrated snippet editor
- extendible with plug-ins
- support for asdoc comments
- package explorer (show classes, symbols from a SWC file)
- basic refactoring
- multiple source code folders per project
- [useful plugins](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=3rd_Party_Plugins_FD4) : ANT integration, SWC creation, mini map, quick navigate

*Cons*

- only for Windows
- no visual designer for MXML
- no support of virtual folders/files inside the project
- weak refactoring
- changing classpaths must be done manually
- plug-ins often not working in newer versions and many plug-ins are only rarely updated
- limited support for debugging Haxe applications

**Common**

*Pros*

- projects for full range of flash apps : websites, AIR (desktop, mobile)
- debugging of FP/AIR apps with breakpoints and stepping
- debugging with watch windows and locals
- support for ASDoc comments
- automatic adding of imports and organizing of imports
- class wizard
- SVG/GIT integration

Cons

- no editing of graphics or animation (use Flash IDE for that)

**Summary**

For debugging, visual design of MXML forms : **Flash Builder**

For coding AS2/AS3/Haxe projects under Windows : **FlashDevelop**

Comment: Fast forward in 2011: FlashDevelop now has a decent debugger, SVN/GIT integration, a class wizard and simple refactoring.

Comment: Updated to include new FD and Flash Builder features.

Comment: AFAIK Flash Builder has always had generation of getters/setters.  Select a member-variable and hit `ctrl`+`1`

Answer (score 1):

Flex builder has a design view for MXML so you can build more visually. Flashdevelop on the other hand is free!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Flash Developer. Trying now FlashDevelop. FlashDevelop is fast and light, and I'm trying to switch just because of that.

I'm using HG + TortoiseHG for source control. I have 2 screens, so having external source control is not a big problem. Also the IDE stays a little cleaner by not having all the little source control icons.

[DesignView](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&offeringid=10299&marketplaceid=1) helps with not having integrated design.

Also, I can debug with FlashDevelop and see the variables. I'm using FD3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Along with what was already mentioned, Flex Builder has some nice tools that helps a developer to learn how to create a data enabled Flex application in form of the **Data Wizards** and also a nice **web services introspection** tool that automatically creates an ActionScript 3 client for a web service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the new Jetbrains IntelliJ 8, and it's great (especially if your used to java developement). Has a lot better XML/JavaScript editors that any other IDE.

The latest version of IntelliJ also has a good flex/javascript debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two objective contrasts between FlashDevelop (with the Flex 3 SDK) and FlexBuilder. First, only FlexBuilder includes AdvancedDataGrid. Second, FlashDevelop has no source control integration.

AdvancedDataGrid is *not* included in either the free or open source Flex 3 SDKs; if you want it, you have to buy FlexBuilder. (I assume it is probably possible to use it via another SDK if you possess FlexBuilder.)

FlashDevelop doesn't have any source control integration, FlexBuilder possesses the existing, stable source control options for Eclipse. This includes Subclipse for SVN, as well as a lot of other things. As a longtime Visual Studio and Emacs user, in FlashDevelop I'm beginning to feel unsatisfied with leaving the editor to check in.

Comment: since the 3.3 version, FlashDevelop have SVN and GIT support added (requires TortoiseSVN or TortoiseGit, enable from settings)

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder, even in version 4.5, has primitive, useless syntax coloring and customization features. From a 700$ package I was expecting at least what I can do with my free text editor.
In the syntax coloring preferences, there is a total of 6 keywords, and you cannot add any custom one.
How am I expected to code having variable names, function calls, and classes look exactly the same?
I will stick to Flash Pro CS5.5 and SciTe.